# Problem playing sound on Timer

Tags: android

I have started a Timer on a screen , for example 20 seconds.

When the time remaining is 5 seconds , I am playing a beep sound .
The problem is that the sound is being played multiple times(3-4 times) , whereas I need a single beep . The duration of the audio file is 0.09 seconds.

Kindly find below the code

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            long timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

            if (timeLeft == 5) {
                   playAlertSound(R.raw.beep);

                }
    }

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    public void playAlertSound(int sound) {

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.release();
            }

        });
        // and add the setLooping and setVolume calls here..
        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
        mp.start(); // to here..
}
```

Kindly provide your inputs/suggestions , where the problem is

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of timer are you using? (Probably a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is the better way to do it). It is hard to answer the question if you don't provide the details, but I'm guessing that the onTick method is called multiple times. The condition you are using will evaluate to true for a numerous values of the millisUntilFinished parameter. You should make sure that onTick is called only once per second for example. Another solution will be to add a flag variable of boolean type that will mark the audio being played once. You will change the condition to also test if this variable is false, before playing the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .  First of all , I am using CountDownTimer  to start the Timer . I am using a class which is extending the CountDownTimer. The above source code is the main functionality . Kindly inform if you need any other source code for reference.

Comment: And what is the countDownInterval? It should be equal or more than 1000.

Comment: Thanks kgiannakakis for your insight ... the interval was set as 100 which caused the issue of multiple beep sounds within a second

Comment: @kgiannakakis I am doing the same with Time interval of 1000 but it works for 30 seconds only and then it gives "Should have subtitle controller already set"
  Can you give me a work around or solution for the same?